# Importing resource conditionally in spring application context

Tags: java, spring

Can I import things in a spring context only if a certain condition is met?

```
<!-- import ONLY IF current environment is NOT testing -->
<import resource="classpath:context/caching-context.xml" />
```

currently I am doing that by importing a totally different context in my testcases

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:ApplicationContextTesting.xml" })
```

but maybe there is a more elegant solution to not maintain two separate application contexts for production and testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Spring profiles.

```
<beans profile="not_test">
   <import resource="classpath:context/caching-context.xml" />
</beans>
```

More information in [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-env-profiles) and on the [blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/).

Comment: This will only work if it's put at the end of the configuration file, so no bean definitions after that (Spring 3.2)