# Variable Spring Security authentication-provider List

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I would like to add authentication-providers to my authentication-manager conditionally, and am having trouble figuring out how to do so.

Suppose I have the following authentication-manager defined:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="myAuthenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
    <security:authentication-provider ref='ldapAuthenticationProvider'/>
    <security:authentication-provider ref='adLdapAuthenticationProvider'/>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='dbAthenticationService'>
        <security:password-encoder ref="myPasswordDigest">
            <security:salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

As it stands, like this, Spring Security is functioning; I can authenticate against LDAP, or Active Directory, or my database. I can also choose to remove one of the providers, and things still continue to function properly, so that's all good.

However, I was hoping that, using Spring profiles, that I could dynamically populate the authentication-provider list. So, for instance, at the end of my application context, I'd have

```
<beans profile="db">
   <!-- Somehow add the following to myAuthenticationManager
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='dbAthenticationService'>
        <security:password-encoder ref="myPasswordDigest">
            <security:salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider> -->
</beans>
<beans profile="ldap">
    <!-- Somehow add the following to myAuthenticationManager
    <security:authentication-provider ref='ldapAuthenticationProvider'/> -->
</beans>
<beans profile="ad">
    <!-- Somehow add the following to myAuthenticationManager
    <security:authentication-provider ref='adLdapAuthenticationProvider'/> -->
</beans>
```

I've already got profile-switching mechanisms in place, and each of these Prodviders are individually configured correctly. I just want to dynamically populate the list of which ones to use on initialization. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: you could put authentication manager part in separate xml files and import at the end of the main xml file based on the profile. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711760/

Comment: @Ritesh ...but what if more than one profile is active? Won't it then try to import multiple beans with the same name?

Comment: You are right. It won't support multiple profiles.

Comment: If you can change code of each provider then you can access the environment (make them EnvironmentAware) in providers and return null from the authenticate method if the supported profile is not active.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to register a single authentication provider. This provider (see below) has a reference to all the authentication providers and forwards to the right provider.

I haven't tested the solution.

```
public class CompositeAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final AuthenticationProvider provider = getAuthenticationProvider(authentication.getClass());

        if(provider == null){
            throw new ProviderNotFoundException("The authentication [" +authentication
                  + "] is not supported by any provider");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return getAuthenticationProvider(authentication) != null;
    }

    private AuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider(Class<?> authentication) {
        for (AuthenticationProvider provider : providers) {
            if (provider.supports(authentication)) {
                return provider;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setProviders(List<AuthenticationProvider> providers) {
        this.providers.addAll(providers); // you could order them with @Order, just use a sorter
    }
}
```

The XML definition:

```
<bean id="compositeAuthenticationProvider"
      class="CompositeAuthenticationProvider" autowire-candidate="false"/>
```